# SSPI Provider: Server not found in Kerberos database

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, kerberos

I'm trying to connect from Ubuntu 20.04 client to the MS SQL Server 2014 located on windows server 2012R2.

Realm joins and Kinit are fine.

```sh
# sudo realm discover org.internal --install=/
org.internal
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: ORG.INTERNAL
  domain-name: org.internal
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: sssd-tools
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: libnss-sss
  required-package: libpam-sss
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-bin
  login-formats: %U@org.internal
  login-policy: allow-realm-logins

# kinit -V user@ORG.INTERNAL
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_0
Using principal: user@ORG.INTERNAL
Password for user@ORG.INTERNAL:
Authenticated to Kerberos v5


# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: user@ORG.INTERNAL

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
12/17/21 10:49:31  12/17/21 20:49:31  krbtgt/ORG.INTERNAL@ORG.INTERNAL
        renew until 12/24/21 10:49:24
12/17/21 10:51:21  12/17/21 20:49:31  MSSQLSvc/ws2012r2:1433@ORG.INTERNAL
        renew until 12/24/21 10:49:24
12/17/21 10:51:57  12/17/21 20:49:31  user@ORG.INTERNAL
        renew until 12/24/21 10:49:24
12/17/21 10:52:30  12/17/21 20:49:31  MSSQLSvc/ws2012r2.org.internal:1433@ORG.INTERNAL
        renew until 12/24/21 10:49:24
```

When I do sqlcmd, I got below error. Note if I specify username and password (sql authentication) it will work.

```sh
# sqlcmd -S 20.12.34.567
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : SSPI Provider: Server not found in Kerberos database.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Cannot generate SSPI context.


SPN is below
setspn -L user

Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=User ABC,CN=Users,DC=org,DC=internal: 
        MSSQLSvc/ws2012r2:1433
```

Any help is much appreciated!

One question here, I did generate a keytab file. However what's the command to tell SQL Server 2014 on windows server 2012r2 to use the keytab file?

Comment: Could be a DNS issue. If, on the client computer, you do a forward lookup of the server's name and a reverse lookup of the server's IP address do they produce the mirrored results?

Comment: Could be a clock sync problem. Are the server, KDC and the client all NTP synced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the server via IP won't allows DNS name-based SPN to work. The SPN with the IP address is not registered. Use the domain name of the server.

Comment: Thank you so much! sqlcmd -S ws2012r2   works! I didn't realize I need to use the domain name

Comment: @Michael-O - You looking for a side gig, by any chance?  I've seen you in here for years, and I need your help with something: developing something to read the Kerberos PAC and a little bit more.  Paying well, and by the hour.  :-)